# Best way to broadcast Armadillo matrix operations similar to Numpy

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

Consider the matrices A and B where A is a `5x5` matrix and B is a `1x5` matrix (or a row vector). If I try to do `A + B` in Numpy, its broadcasting capabilities will implicitly create a `5x5` matrix where each row has the values of B and then do normal matrix addition between those two matrices. This can be written in Armadillo like this;

```
mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
mat B = randu<mat>(1,5);
A + B;
```

But this fails. And I have looked at the documentation and couldn't find a built-in way to do broadcasting. So I want to know the best (fastest) way to do an operation similar to the above.

Of course, I could manually resize the smaller matrix into the size of the larger, and copy the first-row value to each other row using a for loop and use the overloaded `+` operator in Armadillo. But, I'm hoping that there is a more efficient method to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check out the .each_row() function.  E.g. A.each_row() += B

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I must have missed this part of the documentation, but knowing this will be very helpful for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on the note from Claes Rolen. Broadcasting for matrices in Armadillo is done using [.each_col()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow) and  [.each_row()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow). Broadcasting for [cubes](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube) is done with [.each_slice()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_slice).

```
mat A(4, 5, fill::randu);

colvec V(4, fill::randu);
rowvec R(5, fill::randu);

mat X = A.each_col() + V;  // or A.each_col() += V for in-place operation
mat Y = A.each_row() + R;  // or A.each_row() += R for in-place operation

cube C(4, 5, 2, fill::randu);
cube D = C.each_slice() + A;  // or C.each_slice() += A for in-place operation
```

Comment: Thank you! Knowing this will make my tasks much easier.